# Change default program "edit original" on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I change the default program for edit original linked file?

My default is another program (MS Paint), I want to change it to Photoshop, how can I change this?

Comment: Welcome yuan-h! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site or their forum. We are confident you will find answers.

Comment: There are still lots of designers complaining about this.

The "change default program" method in Windows is still an issue because it makes it so you have to open Photoshop every time you want to view an image.

This is the way I fixed the button to work properly:

1. get the photoshop.exe filepath ( for me, that's C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2019\Photoshop.exe)

2. Open Registry Editor and go to: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\edit\command

3. Modify the data by replacing the path inside the quotes, with the photoshop path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program that open up on clicking the " edit original " depends on the file format of that particular file which you want to get opened.If the file is of an image format like .jpeg .jpg .png etc , usually MS Paint open up as it is the default photo editor in windows for the above file extensions.If the linked file is of .psd format,then the Photoshop will open up as it is it's default program.

So if you want to open Photoshop on clicking "edit original" for image files,simply go and change the default program for image files to Photoshop.

Open an image in your explorer > right click > Open with > Choose default program > Select photoshop !

Now you can open photoshop to edit the orginal files ( image files ) in illustrator.

Comment: Which means that all .jpgs will now open in potoshop instead of a viewer, unless explicitly told so? Oh woe is me!